# CollectionView IBOutlet inside a UIView class is returning nil - only sometimes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uicollectionview

So I am trying to discover new ways of keeping my projects clean, and easier to manage for myself.

The way I am hoping to do it, is by keeping everything of relation in it's own swift file, and then calling upon it when it is needed.

I will try my best to layout my issue, but if screenshots help, or if you need any additional info, I will do my best to provide it.

One thing to note: The collection view loads when the app first starts, as it should. And the MenuActionLabel.text outlet, is set to: 'Hi'.

But when I try to call ShowMe(), the CollectionView doesn't reload, and it instead crashes, because Collectioner has returned nil optional.

```
import UIKit

class UserMenu: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    struct Variables {
        static var myName = "Hi"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var Collectioner: UICollectionView!
```

When I call the following 'ShowMe()' function, I get the print out of "coll: nil".

I call the function from ViewController.swift, by 'UserMenu().ShowMe()'

```
    func ShowMe() {
        Variables.myName = "Justin"
        print("coll: \(self.Collectioner)")
        //Collectioner.reloadData()
        //^---- causes error - see didSelectItem for my problem...
        //returns nil optional...? Why?
    }

    //testing to find errors
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        if collectionView == Collectioner {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    //testing to find errors
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if collectionView == Collectioner {
                return 1
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }

    //testing to find errors
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == Collectioner {
            let Cell:UserMenuCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UserMenuCell
            Cell.MenuActionLabel.text = "\(Variables.myName)"
            return Cell
        } else {
            let Cell:UserMenuCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UserMenuCell
            return Cell
        }
    }

    //testing to find errors
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            cell.alpha = 1
        }
    }

    //testing to find errors
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if collectionView == Collectioner {
            return CGSize(width: Collectioner.frame.width, height: 50)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: Collectioner.frame.width, height: 50)
        }
    }

    //testing to find errors
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if collectionView == Collectioner {
            return 0
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
```

My confusion presents itself here:

```
    /*
    When I tap on the cell:
    1. The collection view reloads, and the updated data is shown.

    2. Yet... if I call reloadData from elsewhere,
       the Collectioner outlet returns as an optional nil?
    */

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == Collectioner {
            print(collectionView)
            print(" ")
            print(Collectioner)
            print(" ")
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

The printed output from didSelectItemAt is:

```
<UICollectionView: 0x7fd13103a000; frame = (0 0; 314 716); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60c000242a00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c00022d140>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {314, 50}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fd12ef1b450>

some(<UICollectionView: 0x7fd13103a000; frame = (0 0; 314 716); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60c000242a00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c00022d140>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {314, 50}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fd12ef1b450>)
```

And the collection view flashes, indicating that it has reloaded.

So why is it returning nil, when I try to reload the collection view from anywhere else?

Please help. It's driving me crazy. I have tried everything I can think of, and have done a lot of hunting for answers, solutions and am open to suggestions and learning.

I am not sure if I need to somehow 'confirm' the IBOutlet upon launch, even though everything seems to be connected properly via the StoryBoard.

EDIT - ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let userMenu = UserMenu()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Tapped Button")
        UserMenu().ShowMe()
    }

}
```

EDIT - Heirachy
[image: fig 1]

Cheers,

Justin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let talk about what happens when you call `UserMenu().ShowMe()`

- First, `UserMenu()` is called and initialize a new `UserMenu` instance by using `init()` method.
- Second, this instance will call `ShowMe()` method.

Why do you get crash? - Because the `UserMenu` instance is initialized by default `init` method and nothing is loaded from Storyboard. Of course, in this case, `Collectioner` will be `nil` and it causes crash.

To fix it, you should keep `UserMenu` instance inside `ViewControler` as a property (maybe name it as `userMenu`). Each time you want to call `ShowMe()` method, it should be `userMenu.ShowMe()`.

**EDIT**: Connect User Menu view from Storyboard to `@IBOutlet weak var userMenu: UserMenu!` and use my code below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var userMenu: UserMenu!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
  @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Tapped Button")
    userMenu.ShowMe()
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. I have not used init() anywhere? Also, if I call UserMenu().ShowMe() from ViewController.swifts' viewDidLoad() - it prints out "Justin". So why wouldn't it also reload the collectionView if everything is connected? If I am missing something, i'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: `UserMenu()` is equal to `UserMenu.init()`. I think that's what you are missing.

Comment: Actually I need to see your code inside `viewDidLoad` to know why it happens. Maybe you should add all code inside `viewDidLoad` and where you create `UserMenu`

Comment: When you call UserMenu().ShowMe() , `ShowMe()` method is called and it prints out "Justin". But at this time, `Collectioner` is `nil` because `UserMenu` is initialized by using `init()` method and it causes crash

Comment: So by me calling UserMenu() from viewDidLoad in ViewController.swift, it's basically the same as UserMenu.init()...? Also the edit on your question is how my ViewController is already setup, but yet, the only error I get is that my Collecioner outlet is nil, even though it registers as collectionView == Collectioner during the cell setup etc. Okay, will add ViewController code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Again, Collecioner outlet is nil because you are using `init` method to initialize `UserMenu` object. To fix it, initialize `UserMenu` object by loading it from nib

Comment: @JustinCoates Also add an image where is `UserMenu` in storyboard and I will tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I think I am understanding, but am not really too sure how I would. Could you please give me an example on how I could do something like this?

Comment: You just need to add your storyboard, i will show you how to make it work right way.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: You are a LEGEND! Thank you so much for your help! <3 Have to admit, feel a little silly after all it was so simple >.<!! Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome my friend ! Don't be shy, it isn't simple if you have never do it. Great to help you :D.